# Rdf and Taxonomie

Tags: java

I want to display my result of this program as a tree. I need a hand to finish my work and thank you in advance.

The program works with JDK 8 and Version 3 jena. Here is my code:

```
private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jButton4ActionPerformed
         jTextArea1.setText("");
         Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
          InputStream in = FileManager.get().open("C:/Users/SAMSUNG/Desktop/WICM2/projet/opus_august2007.rdf");
          Model m = model.read(in,null);
          NodeIterator nit = m.listObjects();
          List<String> lclass = new ArrayList<>();
          Map<String,List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
           StmtIterator si = m.listStatements();
           while(si.hasNext()){
               Statement statement = si.next();
             if(statement.getPredicate().getLocalName().equalsIgnoreCase("subClassOf")){
                 String mere = statement.getObject().toString();
                 String fils = statement.getSubject().getLocalName();
                 if(map.containsKey(mere)){
                     List<String> l = map.get(mere);
                     l.add(fils);
                     map.replace(mere, l);
                 }else{
                     List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
                     l.add(fils);
                     map.put(mere, l);
                 }
             }
               if(statement.getObject().isResource() && statement.getPredicate().getLocalName().equalsIgnoreCase("type")){
                   if(!lclass.contains(statement.getSubject().getLocalName())){
                     lclass.add(statement.getSubject().getLocalName())  ;
                   }
               }
           }
           jTextArea1.append("Les classes:\n");
           for(String classe:lclass){
               jTextArea1.append(classe+"\n");
           }
           jTextArea1.append("Les classe et les sous classes:\n");
           for(String l : map.keySet()){
               jTextArea1.append("Classe mere : "+l+"\n");
               for(String s:map.get(l)){
                   jTextArea1.append("   Classe fils:"+s+"\n");


               }
           }
    }
```

This  is  the output  of my program: 
[image]

I want an output   in jTree like that: 
[image]

Or a simple program of the tree in java gui would be okay. Thanks

Comment: Could you just explain yourself more precisely? Is there a bug in your code or you don't see how to approach a specific problem?

Comment: Thanks  sir for your  answer , I show you not just the results of this program under fome tree, its just the program works well but I have the display mode will be in tree form and i hope you understand me –

Comment: Please provide examples of the output your program is currently producing and the output you want.

Comment: thank you sir, I have modified my question and I add 2 to represent a picture display program and my 2nd to present the display I want for this program